# Convert string to Color in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I am encountering a problem which is how do I convert input strings like "RED" to the actual Color type `Color.Red` in C#. Is there a good way to do this?

I could think of using a switch statement and cases statement for each color type but I don't think that is clever enough.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
 Color red = Color.FromName("Red");
```

The MSDN doesn't say one way or another, so there's a good chance that it is case-sensitive.  (UPDATE: Apparently, it is not.)

As far as I can tell, `ColorTranslator.FromHtml` is also.

If `Color.FromName` cannot find a match, it returns `new Color(0,0,0);`

If `ColorTranslator.FromHtml` cannot find a match, it throws an exception.

UPDATE:

Since you're using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color, this gets a bit tricky:

```
using XColor = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color;
using CColor = System.Drawing.Color;

 CColor clrColor = CColor.FromName("Red"); 
 XColor xColor = new XColor(clrColor.R, clrColor.G, clrColor.B, clrColor.A);
```

Comment: Hey James,thx for your comment.Since I am developing this in the XNA GameStudio,after I input your code,the program complains:
     Error 1 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color' does not    contain a definition for 'FromName' and no extension method 'FromName' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Guoguo\Desktop\MapWorld2\MapWorld\GameObject.cs 194 27 MapWorld

 Do you what the error is?Thanks.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the different behavior when a match isn't found.

Comment: Microsoft.Xna.Framework is not the right namespace. Use System.Drawing

Comment: This is a method found in System.Drawing.Color, not (apparently) Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color.

Comment: @StingyJack: You can't ask the OP to change which type he's interested in! Admittedly it would have been nice to have been *told* what type he was interested in to start with...

Comment: The edit assumes the set of colors in `System.Drawing.Color` is the same as that in the XNA `Color` type. That may or may not be the case... and may or may not be important (the OP may be happy with the range of colors in `System.Drawing`).

Comment: Thanks all guys for your input!
I got the Jame's final version of code working,and I will study two other methods posted.

Answer (score 22):

```
System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("Red");
```

(Use my method if you want to accept HTML-style hex colors.)

Answer (score 15):

(It would really have been nice if you'd mentioned which `Color` type you were interested in to start with...)

One simple way of doing this is to just build up a dictionary via reflection:

```
public static class Colors
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Color> dictionary =
        typeof(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                    BindingFlags.Static)
                     .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
                     .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name,
                                   prop => (Color) prop.GetValue(null, null)));

    public static Color FromName(string name)
    {
        // Adjust behaviour for lookup failure etc
        return dictionary[name];
    }
}
```

That will be relatively slow for the first lookup (while it uses reflection to find all the properties) but should be very quick after that.

If you want it to be case-insensitive, you can pass in something like `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as an extra argument in the `ToDictionary` call. You can easily add `TryParse` etc methods should you wish.

Of course, if you only need this in one place, don't bother with a separate class etc :)

Comment: Looks like this is the best way to answer the reverse of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392030/convert-a-xna-color-object-to-a-string

Answer (score 12):

It depends on what you're looking for, if you need System.Windows.Media.Color (like in WPF) it's very easy:

```
System.Windows.Media.Color color = (Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red");//or hexadecimal color, e.g. #131A84
```

Answer (score 8):

Since the OP mentioned in a comment that he's using `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color` rather than `System.Drawing.Color` you can first create a System.Drawing.Color then convert it to a `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color`

```
public static Color FromName(string colorName)
{
    System.Drawing.Color systemColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(colorName);   
    return new Color(systemColor.R, systemColor.G, systemColor.B, systemColor.A); //Here Color is Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color
}
```

Comment: The second line should be: 
Color xnaColor = new Color(systemColor.R, systemColor.G, systemColor.B, systemColor.A);

But I belive this is the simplest way to accomplish what Robert asked.

Comment: ...and a proper `return` statement should be added too :)

Answer (score 5):

For transferring colors via xml-strings I've found out:

```
Color x = Color.Red; // for example
String s = x.ToArgb().ToString()
... to/from xml ...
Int32 argb = Convert.ToInt32(s);
Color red = Color.FromArgb(argb);
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked nicely for my needs ;) Hope someone can use it....

```
    public static Color FromName(String name)
    {
        var color_props= typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
        foreach (var c in color_props)
            if (name.Equals(c.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return (Color)c.GetValue(new Color(), null);
        return Colors.Transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way:

```
string input = null;
Color color = Color.White;

TextBoxText_Changed(object sender, EventsArgs e)
{
   input = TextBox.Text;
}

Button_Click(object sender, EventsArgs e)
{
   color = Color.FromName(input)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following can generate a color from **name**, **hex**, or **known name**.

```
Color beige = StringToColor("Beige");
Color purple = StringToColor("#800080");
Color window = StringToColor("Window");

public static Color StringToColor(string colorStr)
{
    TypeConverter cc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color));
    var result = (Color)cc.ConvertFromString(colorStr);
    return result;
}
```

The snippet was taken from Jo Albahari's [C# in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/).

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: 'TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String.'` is what I get when I try this

Answer (score -2):

I've used something like this before:

```
        public static T CreateFromString<T>(string stringToCreateFrom) {

        T output = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        if (!output.GetType().IsEnum)
            throw new IllegalTypeException();

        try {
            output = (T) Enum.Parse(typeof (T), stringToCreateFrom, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            string error = "Cannot parse '" + stringToCreateFrom + "' to enum '" + typeof (T).FullName + "'";
            _logger.Error(error, ex);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(error, ex);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: @Jon I got mixed up with ConsoleColor. The same logic could still apply though... right? Instead of Enum.Parse() he can do a case insensitive compare on property names and return the result. (obviously removing the IsEnum check).

Comment: I think finding the property by reflection each time would be relatively painful. Better, IMO, to build a dictionary once (as per my answer).

Comment: @Jon Yeah I saw it after I refreshed.