# CallByName, set BackColor

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, callbyname

We want to dynamically (depending on a XML File) set the `BackColor` of a Control in Windows Forms.

I just tried the `CallByName`-Method with `CallType.Method`.

`CallByName(ColorObject, "FromName", CallType.Method, "Red")`

When I want to execute the "FromName" Method it doesn't work, because I need it like this "Color.FromName".

The CallByName got a object from the Class "Color" but still doesn't work. The "Color"-Class is imported.

Does anybody got an idea what I'm doing wrong or how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether the control name and the colour are in the Xml so I will cover both.

What you want is [Controls.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp) and [Color.FromName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391462/convert-string-to-color-in-c-sharp)

So combining you can do something like this:

```
Dim ctl = Me.Controls.Find("Controlname from Xml", True) 'omit the True if you don't need to search child controls as it will be faster
Dim myColour = Color.FromName("ColourName From Xml")
ctl.backColor = myColour
```

Note that the colour name must be one of the standard .Net colours in the [KnownColor Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx) otherwise it will throw an exception

Comment: Thanks :) But we need to dynamically choose the method. We solved this problem with "CallByName" so we can extract a String from a XML File and call the suitable method. The problem with with "FromName" is, that we need the "Color" in front of it (Color.FromName). And with CallByName we aren't able to export "Color.FromName" as a String. That way CallByName doesn't find any method.