# Is it possible to assign color to a C# TextBox based on a SQL table with that information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors

The following code reads perfectly the values I am looking to fill in textboxes and compare for other calculations. But, at the same time, one of them, the `getColorFromTable = dataReader["ReqCol"].ToString();` returns the colorof the device being calculated. I am trying to find a way that the application reads the same color from the table and assign it to the following:
`txPaintColorUpdate.ForeColor` and `txPaintColorUpdate.BorderColor`

So, there are four colors in the table: Red, Orange, Green and Light Blue. After the calculation occurs, the system assigns the type of color to the device, but as an indicator, should change the color of `txPaintColorUpdate` as mentioned above.

Here is a portion of code:

```
                conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader dataReader;
            dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.Read())
            {
                minimumFlowCapacity = dataReader["MinFC"].ToString();
                maximumFlowCapacity = dataReader["MaxFC"].ToString();
                getColorFromTable = dataReader["ReqCol"].ToString();
                getClassification = dataReader["Class"].ToString();
            }
```

Thus, variable `getColorFromTable` is receiving the name of the color from the table and displaying it in the TextBox (`txPaintColorUpdate`). Any advice how to read the same color name so C# can assign it to the TextBox? I know that the common way to do that is invoking `txPaintColorUpdate.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;` and `txPaintColorUpdate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;`, but maybe there is an easier way without doing a lot of `if()` `else{}` statements.

This is a portion of code of when the calculation is made and should assign the color to the TextBox:

```
               if (flow20PSI >= Convert.ToDouble(minimumFlowCapacity) && flow20PSI <= Convert.ToDouble(maximumFlowCapacity))
            {
                txPaintColorUpdate.Text = getColorFromTable;

                //txPaintColorUpdate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color(txPaintColorUpdate.);
                //txPaintColorUpdate.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391462/convert-string-to-color-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Etienne, your solution led me to find the one I needed using this:

```
public static Color FromName(string colorName)

{
    System.Drawing.Color systemColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(colorName);   
    return new Color(systemColor.R, systemColor.G, systemColor.B, systemColor.A); //Here Color is Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color
}
```

From: [Convert string to Color in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391462/convert-string-to-color-in-c-sharp)

My solution was only using this: `System.Drawing.Color systemColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(getColorFromTable);`